# SSIS 2015 Script task convert text file to UTF8 in C# or VB

Tags: c#, t-sql, ssis, azure-synapse

I want to convert my resulting txt file into a UTF8 formatted file so I can load it into my Azure SQL DW via Polybase. It is required the source file be in UTF8.

MSDN has an "IO Streaming example" [HERE](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-load-polybase-guide/) works perfectly for a single job. I am trying to architect an SSIS solution for around 30 tables though. I believe using this method would cause a race condition where the PS script will be locked by 1 SSIS package when another SSIS package needs it.

I am a sql dev, not a .NET dev so please forgive me. How would one convert the above to an SSIS C# Script task assuming I know how to pass parameters into the Script task?

### PowerShell Code from MSDN

```
#Static variables
$ascii = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
$utf16le = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
$utf8 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$ansi = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
$append = $False

#Set source file path and file name
$src = [System.IO.Path]::Combine("<MySrcFolder>","<MyUtf8stage>.txt")

#Set source file encoding (using list above)
$src_enc = $ascii

#Set target file path and file name
$tgt = [System.IO.Path]::Combine("<MyDestFolder>","<MyFinalstage>.txt")

#Set target file encoding (using list above)
$tgt_enc = $utf8

$read = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($src,$src_enc)
$write = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($tgt,$append,$tgt_enc)

while ($read.Peek() -ne -1)
{
    $line = $read.ReadLine();
    $write.WriteLine($line);
}
$read.Close()
$read.Dispose()
$write.Close()
$write.Dispose()
```

---

### Update

I found a similar post which I was able to tweak to my needs, I swear I searched high and low before posting. Anyway here is what IS working for me. If you see anyway to improve it please share:

```
public void Main()
    {
        //$Package::SourceSQLObject = tablename
        //$Package::StageFile_DestinationFolderPath = rootpath eg "C:\temp\"

        string path = (string)Dts.Variables["$Package::StageFile_DestinationFolderPath"].Value;
        string name = (string)Dts.Variables["$Package::SourceSQLObject"].Value;
        string from = Path.Combine(path, name) + ".csv";
        string to = Path.ChangeExtension(from, "txt");
        Dts.Log("Starting " + to.ToUpper(), 0, null);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(from, Encoding.ASCII, false, 10))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(to, false, Encoding.UTF8, 10))
        {
            while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: Hey Brady, if this solution worked for you, can you post this as an answer and then mark it later. It helps with the search. Thank you

Comment: I think I have done what you requested. Let me know if i can do something different.

Comment: Looks good. Thank you Brady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Main()
    {
        //$Package::SourceSQLObject = tablename
        //$Package::StageFile_DestinationFolderPath = rootpath eg "C:\temp\"

        string path = (string)Dts.Variables["$Package::StageFile_DestinationFolderPath"].Value;
        string name = (string)Dts.Variables["$Package::SourceSQLObject"].Value;
        string from = Path.Combine(path, name) + ".csv";
        string to = Path.ChangeExtension(from, "txt");
        Dts.Log("Starting " + to.ToUpper(), 0, null);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(from, Encoding.ASCII, false, 10))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(to, false, Encoding.UTF8, 10))
        {
            while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code indicates that your are trying to convert an ASCII file to UTF-8 however that [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-load-polybase-guide/) also states the following:

> As UTF-8 uses the same character encoding as ASCII PolyBase will also
>   support loading data that is ASCII encoded.

So my advice to you is to try the file first with Polybase, check for any conversion issues before you spend any time trying to convert the files.

Comment: I was trying to keep my question short a succinct. The solution only works if I convert the files to UTF8. That is why the process works if I use PS conversion and does not work if I do not use the PS conversion. Thank you for your feedback?

Comment: Strange, I have had experience loading ASCII files via Polybase and it worked perfectly well.  Presumably you get a specific error?  It might be useful to post that for future viewers of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mySrcFolder = ""; // something from user variables?
var myUtf8stage = ""; // something from user variables?
var myFinalstage = ""; // something from user variables?

// Static variables
var ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
var utf16le = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
var utf8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
var ansi = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
var append = false;

// Set source file path and file name
var src = System.IO.Path.Combine(
    mySrcFolder,
    String.Format("{0}.txt", myUtf8stage));

// Set source file encoding (using list above)
var src_enc = ascii;

// Set target file path and file name
var tgt = System.IO.Path.Combine(
    mySrcFolder,
    String.Format("{0}.txt", myFinalstage));

// Set target file encoding (using list above)
var tgt_enc = utf8;

using (var read = new System.IO.StreamReader(src, src_enc))
using (var write = new System.IO.StreamWriter(tgt, append, tgt_enc))
{
    while (read.Peek() != -1)
    {
        var line = read.ReadLine();
        write.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting errorsa with this. I added my package parameters:

Comment: at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   .....